# managing unlockables on mysql databases

Tags: mysql, database

Well how may I put this, I'm working on a user database, and each user will have some unlock-ables.

So I'm not sure whats the best method to manage those kinds of data, should I have a table with each unlock-able and a quantity value for each one, and link it to the users? Or is there a better way? Or maybe I could use 2 databases, one for the users, and one for the unlockables?

I honestly think my idea of how this works isn't the best one because if I have 1000 possible unlockables, each user would have to be linked to a table with 1000 possibilities. Also if I wanted to add new items, I would have to update a large database this way.

Comment: like features they can unlock somehow.

Comment: Features in your program? Your going to have to provide more detail

Comment: Users can have any number of these features? Do you need to keep track of the unlock/lock of these features for each user? As @Lock pointed out, you need to provide more details. Features can be repeated for one user? I mean, the quantity or amount of these features assigned to one user can be more than 1?

Comment: @yaroslav yes, the reason i said quantity and not boolean is because it can be more than 1, think about it like a virtual shopping cart, even tho there wont be any shopping, users will spend virtual points getting virtual items, and i need to keep track of what items they have and how many of each one.
and also the unlock/lock needs to be tracked, because they wont be able to get items they haven't unlocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

What i answered was a really bad idea, it works but in relational databases is considered a bad practice, since you don't want to have a mashup of items in one field, its better to use several tables to normalize this. That being said if your are using noSql you could use something like i proposed but instead of using a concatenated string you would use an associative array(json) structure to hold these values.

---

Inside your users table, create a column, called "unlockables" or w/e you think is the best (put "text" as the data type) and everytime a user gets one of those unlockables you add it to this field separated by an "*" or anything you want, if those unlockables also have quantities you may also add a second separator like this "ID+Quantity*ID+Quantity" so lets say you have 3 items with the followings ids (12,45,89) and this equivalent quantity (1,6,2), you add it like this (12+1*45+6*89+2) then when you retrieve this value using php you explode the string twice, first using the "*", then use the "+", and you will have an array with your data, you could also create a second table for this but that's your choice, this is just a fast way to go with what you want, i hope this can help you out a little.

Comment: thank you, that seems to solve the problem, even tho it feel like there could be an easier way.

Comment: You welcome, this one is pretty easy but i'm sure there must be a better way according to your needs if you find this one to hard. I'm glad i could help.